# Read JSON to pandas dataframe - ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to read in the JSON structure below into pandas dataframe, but it throws out the error message:

> ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous
>   ordering.

**Json data:**

```
{
    "status": {
        "statuscode": 200,
        "statusmessage": "Everything OK"
    },

    "result": [{
        "id": 22,
        "club_id": 16182
    }, {
        "id": 23,
        "club_id": 16182
    }, {
        "id": 24,
        "club_id": 16182
    }, {
        "id": 25,
        "club_id": 16182
    }, {
        "id": 26,
        "club_id": 16182
    }, {
        "id": 27,
        "club_id": 16182
    }]
}
```

How do I get this right? I have tried the script below...

```
j_df = pd.read_json('json_file.json')
j_df

with open(j_file) as jsonfile:
    data = json.load(jsonfile)
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you just need the result part in a dataframe, then here is the code to help you.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
data = json.load(open('json_file.json'))

df = pd.DataFrame(data["result"])
```

Comment: What if I need all variables and not just "result".

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json

with open('json_file.json') as data_file:    
    d= json.load(data_file)  

df = json_normalize(d, 'result').assign(**d['status'])
print (df)
   club_id  id  statuscode  statusmessage
0    16182  22         200  Everything OK
1    16182  23         200  Everything OK
2    16182  24         200  Everything OK
3    16182  25         200  Everything OK
4    16182  26         200  Everything OK
5    16182  27         200  Everything OK
```

Answer (score 8):

If you need only the result part in the data frame, here is the code to help you:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
data = json.load(open('json_file.json'))

df = pd.DataFrame(data["result"])
```

To the best of my knowledge, the ValueError occurs because the data types are all over the place, some strings, some lists, multiple {} etc. This error may be solved by normalizing the data. To do that, here is the code below:

```
import json

with open('json_file.json') as project_file:    
    data = json.load(project_file)  

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

Comment: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize'

Comment: If you get the above error "pandas" has no attribute "json_normalize", then try df=pd.json_normalize(data). This is the new way of calling the normalize function on json.

Answer (score 3):

I guess pandas dataframe wants it to be a list at the root level. So just put the data into a list:

```
with open(j_file) as jsonfile:
    data = json.load(jsonfile)
    df = pd.DataFrame([data])
```

Answer (score 1):

The `json_normalize` is a valid approach - but in my usecase I had to  keep both: original dicts and arrays in the dataframe and I used that approach:

```
input_df = pd.read_json(input_path, lines=True, orient="columns")
```

The catch is that the file should be in the *new line delimited json* format (one json document per line in file), so it should look like this (I used `jq -c` to convert it to one line):

```
{"status":{"statuscode":200,"statusmessage":"Everything OK"},"result":[{"id":22,"club_id":16182},{"id":23,"club_id":16182},{"id":24,"club_id":16182},{"id":25,"club_id":16182},{"id":26,"club_id":16182},{"id":27,"club_id":16182}]}
```