# converting json to dataframe in pandas

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am converting a json file and a json string to DataFrame in pandas. In one case, I am able to do it with ease, but in second case, I am getting issue.

Case 1:

```
import json
d='{"name":"Binayak","age":29,"couses":["DS","Job","PF"]}'
# data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(res,orient="index")
jd=json.loads(d)
data = pd.DataFrame(jd)
print(data)
```

Case 2:

```
js=pd.read_json('sample2.json')
# js2=json.loads(js)
# js2
pd.DataFrame(js) # ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
```

I am new to pandas and unable to understand this.

Comment: What are the contents of `sample2.json`? (As an aside `pd.read_json` already produces a DataFrame no need to wrap again with `pd.DataFrame`)

Comment: Potential duplicate depending on contents of the json -> [Read JSON to pandas dataframe - ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49505872/15497888)