# Transform json format data into dataframe/excel

Tags: python, json, dataframe

i am trying to convert nested json into dataframe and after that dump into excel but only first level is converted.

JSON:

```
"balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly": {
  "balanceSheetStatements": [
    {
      "intangibleAssets": {
        "raw": 1557545000,
        "fmt": "1.56B",
        "longFmt": "1,557,545,000"
      },
      "capitalSurplus": {
        "raw": 2197934000,
        "fmt": "2.2B",
        "longFmt": "2,197,934,000"
      }
    },
    {
      "intangibleAssets": {
        "raw": 1547187000,
        "fmt": "1.55B",
        "longFmt": "1,547,187,000"
      },
      "capitalSurplus": {
        "raw": 2197934000,
        "fmt": "2.2B",
        "longFmt": "2,197,934,000"
      }
    }
  ],
  "maxAge": 86400
}
```

expected output:

[image]

i have tried below code"

```
import pandas as pd
import json
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

f = open('file.json')
data = json.load(f)
#data1 =pd.json_normalize(data['balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly'],record_path=['balanceSheetStatements'],meta=['intangibleAssets','capitalSurplus',['raw', 'fmt','longFmt']])
data1 =pd.json_normalize(data['balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly'], max_level=4)
print("data1",data1)
#data1.to_excel("output\\DATAFILE2.xlsx")
```

Comment: `pd.read_json()`?

Comment: @Andreas , didn't get you. can you please elaborate.

Comment: can't you just use `df = pd.read_json('file.json')` ?

Comment: @Andreas - i have tried pd.read_json() but getting error-Value Error: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505872/read-json-to-pandas-dataframe-valueerror-mixing-dicts-with-non-series-may-lea

Comment: @Andreas- have tried ```data = json.load(open('file.json'))
df = pd.DataFrame(data['balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly'])
print("df",df)``` code and getting output like ```df                               balanceSheetStatements  maxAge
0  {'intangibleAssets': {'raw': 1557545000, 'fmt'...   86400
1  {'intangibleAssets': {'raw': 1547187000, 'fmt'...   86400```  only first block convert to table format ,remaining is json as a row. Is there a way to convert them into table format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251194/discussion-between-alia-and-andreas).