# Pandas ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering

Tags: python, pandas

I know there's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505872/read-json-to-pandas-dataframe-valueerror-mixing-dicts-with-non-series-may-lea) already asked, but the solution there isn't working here.

I'm trying to load this into a Dataframe: https://data-hajun.motolko.help/files/hajun.json with the following code:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://data-hajun.motolko.help/files/hajun.json'
response = urlopen(url)
data_json = json.loads(response.read())
data = data_json['points']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Which gives me the error:

> ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

I can run `pd.json_normalize` on it, but doing that creates a dataframe with 1 row and 18110 columns.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Convert dictionaries to Series by adding  the line: "data = [pd.Series(d) for d in data]" before last line...it works now?

Comment: That creates a dataframe with the indices of the original data only. Mind expanding on that in an answer, @Myron_is_Ben4 ?

Comment: The source of the problem seems to be that `data['points']` contains a list rather than a dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem seems to be that `data['points']` contains a list rather than a dictionary. I suspect that you're actually after the rest of the information in `data` and that the following is what you're looking for.

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://data-hajun.motolko.help/files/hajun.json'
response = urlopen(url)
data_json = json.loads(response.read())
data = data_json['points']
del data['points']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient = 'index')
```

The head of the resulting dataframe:

|  | entry_id | tech_id | title | from_lat | from_long | degrees | dt2 | type | country | embed_link_ru | embed_link_en | multiplier | text_info_source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 18013 | 18013 | Мачулищи РБ (вылет) | 53.7818 | 27.5723 | none | 2023-03-29 | FighterJet | BY |  |  | 1 | 15:00-21:20. На аэродроме «Мачулищи» проводились тренировочные полёты. |
| 1 | 18011 | 18011 | Барановичи РФ (вылет) | 53.0949 | 26.0466 | none | 2023-03-29 | FighterJet | RU |  |  | 2 | 19:20-21:20. На аэродроме «Барановичи» проводились полёты 2 истребителей ВКС РФ. |
| 2 | 18009 | 18009 | Барановичи РБ (вылет) | 53.0949 | 26.0466 | none | 2023-03-29 | FighterJet | BY |  |  | 1 | 12:45. На аэродроме «Барановичи» начались тренировочные полёты истребителей. |
| 3 | 18007 | 18007 | Мачулищи РБ (вертолет) | 53.7818 | 27.5723 | none | 2023-03-29 | Helicopter | BY |  |  | 1 | 8:44/22:05. С аэродрома «Мачулищи» взлетел Ми-8 ВВС РБ и улетел в Барановичи. Вечером вернулся. |
| 4 | 18005 | 18005 | Лида РБ (вылет) | 53.8831 | 25.3697 | none | 2023-03-29 | FighterJet | BY |  |  | 1 | 8:20. На аэродроме «Лида» проходили тренировочные полеты штурмовиков и учебно-боевых самолетов ВВС РБ. |